# How to perform a factory reset without access to owner profile?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, factory-reset, password, hard-reset

I recently bought the [RCA Voyager](http://www.walmart.com/ip/38693696?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227028633909&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=t&wl3=48184946792&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=96622731152&veh=sem) 7" tablet from Walmart.

I opened the settings app and added a slide password to my device. When I was finished I clicked 'OK' and the settings app closed and a message popped up saying

> Settings has unexpectedly closed.

I was unable to open the application until I rebooted my tablet. Upon rebooting it asked me for a password and I performed the slide gesture I had set as my password. It said the pattern was incorrect.

(Btw the tablet is running android 4.4)

I tried it again with similar results. Then again. Then again. It finally asked me if I had forgot my password and I tapped yes. It asked me to input my account information (email and password) and I did.

Then a message popped up saying:

> The username or password you have input is incorrect. Please try again.

I decided to input my username in the email text field and it still replied with the above pop up.

I remembered reading online that if I turn the device off and hold the power button and the volume down button simultaneously it would bring up a screen that allows me to wipe my phone.

I know this works because I tried it on my Android 4.0 phone after I downloaded a malicious Ubuntu 'unity' launcher from the Play Store. However the device simply booted up without displaying the options I wanted. I tried inserting a pin into the reset slot but it also didn't work.

I have no access to my device and everything has failed so far. Please help me. **To recap, how can I go about resetting the device?** There has to be some way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the detailed instructions below on how to completely reset your RCA Android 7 Voyager (RCT6773W22) tablet.

**Step 1.** With your tablet off, press and hold the volume up (+) button and power button until you see the RCA splash screen with Nipper and Chipper. Release both  buttons to reveal the Android bot on his back with a caution symbol above him.

**Step 2.** A new screen will appear asking you to use your volume up/down keys to move and the power button to select.

**Step 3.** Use the volume down (-) button to highlight "wipe data/factory reset." Once highlighted, select using the power button.

**Step 4.** A new screen will appear asking you to confirm your selection. Use your volume down (-) button to highlight "Yes -- delete all user data." Press the power button to select once highlighted.

**Step 5.** Once the tablet is finished wiping data, you may press the power button to select "reboot system now." This will restart your tablet.

**Step 6.** The system will begin to reboot and once again display the RCA logo with Nipper and Chipper. The next "Welcome" screen will prompt you to select your language of choice. Scroll through the options using your finger and press start when finished. Congratulations, you have successfully reset your RCA 7 Voyager tablet.